# How do i expand a binary signed number in char size to signed int size

Tags: c, bit, extend, signed

This function: `int signextend( int value, int size )`
Receives a value in signed binary (most significant bit says the signal `+` if it is 0 or `-` if it is 1) and it receives the size of this binary value.
The goal is to extend the value to a int size signed too. How do I do this?

I know I need 2 if's one if the most significant bit is 1 or 0 to extend it with 1's or 0's but I don't know how to select the most significant bit from the value

Comment: Does `size` specify the size of the source data in bytes or in bits? There have been multiple sign-extensions questions here before, this question may be a duplicate.

Comment: @njuffa size specifies the number of bits in value for example I receive 1011 so size = 4, and I want to select the bit that is in left side, in this case 1. And extend it (int size = 32-size (4 in this case) ) times to the left
So it goes like 11111....111111011

Comment: Does the binary string 1011 of length 4 represent the decimal number -5 (2's complement representation), -4 (1's complement representation), or -3 (sign and magnitude representation)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. These numbers are called sign-magnitude, by the way:

```
int signextend(unsigned int value, unsigned int size)
{
  const unsigned int topmask = 1u << (size - 1);
  if((value & topmask) != 0)
  {
    return -(value & ~topmask);
  }
  return (int) value;
}
```

This makes the arguments `unsigned` since having them signed makes no sense to me.

If called like so: `signextend(0xc, 4);` it will return -4 (`0xc` is `1100` in binary).

Note that this format can express `-0` (consider e.g. `signextend(0x80, 8);`) which of course is not representable as an `int` and will be mapped to 0.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try it out ^^

Comment: It has to be signed if the most significant bit is 1 the number should be extended with 1's. If it is 0 the number should be extended with 0's. It is signed and the difference of extension is there

Answer (score 0):

> size of this binary value

if by this you mean that this is the length of the binary string (for example the int 10 represented by `1010`, would give size = 4) then just do this

```
int b = 8;
int size = 4;
printf("this is the most significant bit %d", b >> size-1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's the stuff i needed